# Connect output with input at same logic gate

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, circuits

Is there a nice way to connect the output with the input of the same logic gate as shown in the following picture?

[image]

My current "code" looks like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, shapes.gates.logic.US, calc}

\begin{document}
\tikzstyle{branch}=[fill,shape=circle,minimum size=3pt,inner sep=0pt]
\begin{tikzpicture}[label distance=2mm, scale=1.5]
    \node (x) at (0, 1) {$x_t$};
    \node[and gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at (1, 1) (and) {};  

    \draw (x) |- (and.input 1);
    \draw (and.output) 
        -- ([xshift=0.5cm] and.output) 
        |- ([yshift=-0.5cm] and.output)
        |- (and.input 2);

    \draw (and.output) -- node[above]{$y$} (2.5, 1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

but this is giving me the following output (also I don't know how to shift a branch on the x-axis lol)

[image]

As always, any help is appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please provide a complete MWE, i.e. a document that starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and can be compiled.

Comment: @marmot edited the post, but you already presented a solution so I'm going to mark it as solved. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no clue about `circuitikz` but I know Ti*k*Z enough to draw some lines...

```
\documentclass[circuitikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\node[and gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at (1, 1) (and) {};  
\draw  (and.input 1) -- ++ (-0.5,0) node[left](x){$x_t$};
\draw (and.output) -- ++ (1,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt](bull){} 
 -- ++ (0.5,0);
 \draw  (and.input 2) -| ++ (-0.5,-0.5) -| (bull);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I add the letter "Q" to the upper right (output) as shown in the first picture? I tried the following code`\draw (or.output) -- ++ (1,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=1pt](bull){$TEXTHERE$} -- ++ (0.5,0);` but that gave me an error message.

Comment: @user019231283 Try `\draw (and.output) -- ++ (1,0) node[circle,fill,inner sep=2pt](bull){} 
 -- ++ (0.5,0) node[right]{$Q$};`

Answer (score 0):

It's more or less the same than @marmot answer, but using the native `circuitikz` connectors and a bit of vertical/horizontal connections:

```
\documentclass[circuitikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone} 
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits.logic.US}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}
\node[and gate US, draw, logic gate inputs=nn] at (1, 1) (and) {};  
\draw  (and.input 1) to[short, -o] ++ (-0.5,0) node[left](x){$x_t$};
\draw (and.output) to[short, -*]  ++ (0.5,0) coordinate(dot) to[short, -o] ++(0.5,0) node[right]{$y_t$};
\draw (dot) -- ++(0, -0.5) -| ([xshift=-0.4cm] and.input 2) -- (and.input 2);
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

The trick here is:

1. use `to[short, -*]` or variants instead of `--` when you want the dots/connectors;
2. use intermediate `coordinate()` to ease drawing;
3. use `([xshift=...]named node)` to have a bit of breath space;
4. use `-|` (draw horizontally, then vertically --- Manhattan geometry is called, I think) where appropriate.

[image]